# How to enable dr_blob extension in the frontend in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I am trying to use the [dr_blob](http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/dr_blob/2.3.2/view/1/2/) extension just to list uploaded files to a TYPO3 site. The problem is after following the tutorial for the basic (which is all what I need) I get no output in the frontend. I didn't create a template file (I use TemplaVoila for templating) as it said there's a basic one included with the extension (copied and tried to use this also) I am unsure of the missing step. Any pointers would be appreciated.

I use TYPO3 4.7.4 with v2.3.2 of the extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you include the `static template` from the extension?

Comment: Is this an answer ? Please post additional questions in the comments.

Comment: always forget to do this all the time >:/